# JMeter User Defined Variable for enabling Test Duration

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am trying to parameterize the JMeter test so that I can run Load Test, Stress Test as well as Soak Load Test using the same test plan.

In order to do this, I defined the following as User Defined variables (Test Plan -> Add -> Config Element -> User Defined Variables)

```
numberOfThreads=${__P(numberOfThreads,1)}
rampUp=${__P(rampUp,1)}
loopCount=${__P(loopCount,1)}
schedulerEnabled=${__P(schedulerEnabled,false)}
schedulerDuration=${__P(schedulerDuration,120)}
```

Now, in the ThreadGroup definition, I am using these variables as

```
<ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Test123" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments">Test for the endpoint GET /test123</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">${loopCount}</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">${numberOfThreads}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">${rampUp}</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">{schedulerEnabled}</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">${schedulerDuration}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
```

But when I run the same and pass in values

```
numberOfThreads=50
rampUp=10
loopCount=-1
schedulerEnabled=true
schedulerDuration=30
```

(using jmeter-maven-plugin)
the first ThreadGroup keeps creating infinite number of threads instead of shutting down the thread groups after 30 seconds.

PS: 30 is an example. When executing Soak Load Test, I will be setting a higher value to the same.

PS: I noticed that LoopController.continue_forever is set to 'false' immaterial whether for Loop Count I check "Infinite" or provide the value 1. When in UI, I check "Infinite", the value of LoopController.loops is set to -1.

- jmeter-maven-plugin: 2.7.0
- JMeter Version: 5.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the correct way to enable/disable the thread lifetime setting:

```
<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">{schedulerEnabled}</boolProp>
```

Instead of trying to enable/disable the thread lifetime setting you could rather play with this `schedulerDuration` setting itself, for example if you plan to run fixed amount of loops - set the duration to something very big, the [maximum value is 9223372036854775807](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE)

Also it should be possible to use [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller)

If ability to enable/disable the scheduler is something you **really** need, you will need to amend it in the .jmx script beforehand somehow, i.e. using [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) editor. Also [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation) framework has possibility to [amend all the properties of all the test elements](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts) using simple YAML syntax

Comment: Thanks!

I removed the schedulerEnabled=${__P(schedulerEnabled,false)}. 

and set to true by default.

Now in order to run Load/Stress test, I know the # of threads and loopCount. I set a high value for duration and the test only executes the # of threads for #loopCount and exits even when the duration is not met.

For Soak Load Test, I specified loopCount=-1 and duration as per the need.